# how to adjust the height of two adjacent cell without using dispaly:table-cell

Tags: css

Can any one help this..
I want to adjust the two adjacent cell height using div tag  without using the display:table-cell. Please reply as soon as possible..

Comment: without using height. because the cell height is dynamic

Comment: you can try to put the <br /> tags in <td>.

Comment: You can use height:100% if it's dynamic.

Comment: Is this for a background or have you got content in these other elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do what you're trying to do using simply CSS.

I'd recommend using a jQuery Equal Heights plugin like this one:

http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/equal-height-columns.html

You simply load jQuery and the plugin onto your page then use it like so:

```
$('.myCLASSorIDorWHATEVER').equalHeightColumns();
```

Hope that helps.